# spark GMM fail to divide points to correct clusters

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-analysis, apache-spark-mllib

I have data set which looks like this: (user names has been obfuscated, also there are 40 users - I didn't want to show them all)

```
(a1,List(1.0, 1015.0))
(a2,List(2.0, 2015.0))
(a3,List(3.0, 3015.0))
(a4,List(1.0, 1015.0))
(a5,List(0.0, 15.0))
(a6,List(0.0, 15.0))
```

Basically, I want to create a sample app where there are 4 clusters which are really obvious (10 users from each cluster). And show that users with same characteristics fall into the same cluster.

The code creates vectors from the data, trains a model and predicts according to the model learned:

```
val cuttedData = data1.map(s => s.replace("List", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "").trim.split(','))
val parsedData1 = cuttedData.map(item => Vectors.dense(item.drop(1).map(t => t.toDouble))).cache()
parsedData1.foreach(println)
val gmm1 = new GaussianMixture().setK(4).run(parsedData1)
cuttedData.foreach(item => {println(item(0) + " : " + gmm1.predict(Vectors.dense(item.drop(1).map(i => i.toDouble))))})
```

The issue is that the users are predicted to only 3 clusters, so that the features -> cluster relations are:

```
(1.0, 1015.0) -> 1
(0.0, 15.0) -> 0
(2.0, 2015.0), (3.0, 3015.0) -> 2
```

the clusters as printed from the model are:

```
weight=0.150000
mu=[2.4445803037860923E-11,15.000000024445805]
sigma=
5.7824573923325105E-11  5.782457392332511E-8  
5.782457392332511E-8    5.782457377877571E-5  

weight=0.150000
mu=[2.4445803037860923E-11,15.000000024445805]
sigma=
5.7824573923325105E-11  5.782457392332511E-8  
5.782457392332511E-8    5.782457377877571E-5  

weight=0.371495
mu=[2.1293846059560595,2144.3846059560597]
sigma=
0.4824411855092578  482.4411855092562  
482.4411855092562   482441.185509255   

weight=0.328505
mu=[1.8536826474572847,1868.6826474572852]
sigma=
0.4795182413266584  479.51824132665774  
479.51824132665774  479518.24132665637
```

I don't understand why the users are classified wrong, I tried increasing the K parameter to 100, and using Normalizer for the data but it didn't help.

Another thing to notice is that when I use KMEANS for the same data it works perfectly.

Comment: This is most likely to be because the size of your data you have is not enough. GMM is different from K-means, K-means clusters based on Euclidean distance, you could have groups of 2 users if the data is sparse enough, GMM does not, GMM treat all your data as a mixture and then re-arrange each slice to minimize a function, it needs to see all the data, including the zeros.

Comment: @GameOfThrows I tried duplicating the data set several times but the results remain the same. Also I tried several seeds for the GMM also with no effect. Is there another thing I can do?

Comment: duplicating the data will not work - as you still have the same problem. Let me give you an example, let's say we are on 1 Dimension data and our cluster are simply numbers: [1,2,101,102] would make 2 Clusters easily using K-means, but this is not the case for GMM - but this might: [0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,101,102,0,0] - see what I mean? The GMM takes each slice and re-arrange them based on a cost function, so it needs to see all the data including the zeros - which is why it is often used to cluster continous distributions.